# Late 90s SF cartoon. Dark dystopian style

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I am seeking for the name of cartoon. I don't known exactly about plot because I had only one episode from VHS. But I remember some things. Style of animation was classic 2D with very realistic drawn. Not much like other cartoons of this era. Drawn was similar to Perfect Blue (1997) anime but in western style. This was not an anime. Models had normal body sizes, heads and eyes. Their had normal clothes not uniforms or something. Even backgrounds like waterfall afar or simple wooden shed authors drawn meticulously.

Now plot from episode that I remember. There was group of young women and men in rural area. They had strange electronically device attached to head. This device was making visible field that make them suffer or made other unpleasant states. Group was desperate, angry and sad. Last scene I remember was girl running away from traitor of group. She locked herself in shed then she wear off device and try making contact with someone by walkie-talkie.

If I remember correctly someone ripped this cartoon from Cartoon Network channel with old 'chess board' logo. I am from East Europe and there was option to change rotation of dish to Hot Bird and receive uncoded CN from US/GB. I was a kid and I wasn't understand English so I don't wrote about dialogues.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this could be the Aeon Flux TV series considering the art style and the use of strange electronic devices and mind control. [AEON FLUX](https://www.mtv.com/shows/aeon-flux)

Comment: Nope. Drawn was far more naturalistic for models and women's had normal size brest :) Also there was more realism. In Aeon Flux Trevor is throwing a rope slide down and kill 50 mens by akimbo. In this cartoon when group is climbing on steppy hill they really struggle and sweating. And Aeon is from 1990. To early.